# Iteratively obtaining different pages of a query using python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to parse a sequence of html pages using python, I am having trouble grabbing the pages in  iterative fashion. The link to the web page.

[Milano Library](http://www.biblioteche.regione.lombardia.it/OPACMI01/cat/SDF?FORMFL_OB=CHIAVE%20DI%20ORDINAMENTO%20DEL%20TITOLO&FORM_SO=Ascend&FORM_C=AND&CODICE_BIBLIO=LO1%2001&CODICE_BIBLIO_O=uguale&CODICE_BIBLIO_C=AND&COPY_BIBLIO=&COPY_BIBLIO_C=AND&GROUP=&AUTORE_O=AND&AUTORE=&TITOLO_O=AND&TITOLO=&SOGGETTO_BW_O=AND&SOGGETTO_BW=&DESCRITTORE_BW_O=&DESCRITTORE_BW=&DESCRITTORE_O=AND&DESCRITTORE=&TIPO_CLASS=&CLASSE_FULL=&CLASSE_FULL_O=AND&COLLANA_O=AND&COLLANA=&TITOLO_ORIGINALE_O=AND&TITOLO_ORIGINALE=&EDITORE_O=AND&EDITORE=sonzogno&ABSTRACT_O=AND&ABSTRACT=&INDIRIZZOWEB_O=&INDIRIZZOWEB=&COLLOCAZIONE_INC_O=&COLLOCAZIONE_INC=&TEMP500A_O=&TEMP200E_O=&TIPO_DOCUMENTO_O=uguale&TIPO_DOCUMENTO=&GENERE_O=uguale&GENERE=&DATA_PUBBLICAZIONE_O=minore&DATA_PUBBLICAZIONE=1943&LUOGO_EDIZIONE_O=AND&LUOGO_EDIZIONE=&PAESE_O=AND&PAESE=&LINGUA_O=AND&LINGUA=&DATA_COLL=&IMPRONTA_O=AND&IMPRONTA=&POSSESSORE_O=AND&POSSESSORE=&MARCHE_O=AND&MARCHE=&NOTE_ESEMP_O=AND&NOTE_ESEMP=&GENERE_A_O=uguale&GENERE_A=)

After peeking through the source, I found a function that responds to the click event on button element for the next page.

```
 function SaltaAPagina() {
    var CalcPag = VAIAPAGINA.value;
    if (CalcPag > 0) {
        CalcPag=CalcPag;
    }
    else {
        CalcPag="1";
     }
    document.location = "/OPACMI01/cat/SDW?W=CODICE_BIBLIO+%3D+%27LO1+01%27+AND+EDITORE+PH+WORDS+%27sonzogno%27+AND+DATA_PUBBLICAZIONE+%3C+1943+ORDER+BY+ORDINAMENTO/Ascend&M=" + CalcPag + "&R=Y";
    }
```

I know that I can encode parameters using pythons urllib2 module using the urlencode method. But I am not sure what I should be including as a parameter

```
lomba_link='http://www.biblioteche.regione.lombardia.it/OPACMI01/cat/SDW?W%3DCODICE_BIBLIO+%3D+%27LO1+01%27+AND+EDITORE+PH+WORDS+%27sonzogno%27+AND+DATA_PUBBLICAZIONE+%3C+1943+ORDER+BY+ORDINAMENTO/Ascend%26M%3D1%26R%3DY'
params = urllib.urlencode([('CalcPag',4)])
# this has not worked.
req = urllib2.Request(lomba_link)
print req
response = urllib2.urlopen(req,params)
html_doc = response.read()
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The javascript function you posted is passing several parameters to the target page:

```
document.location = "/OPACMI01/cat/SDW" + // This is the path of the page
     "?W=CODICE_BIBLIO+%3D+%27LO1+01%27+AND+EDITORE+PH+WORDS+%27sonzogno%27+AND+DATA_PUBBLICAZIONE+%3C+1943+ORDER+BY+ORDINAMENTO/Ascend" + // The first parameter
     "&M=" + CalcPag + // The second parameter
     "&R=Y"; // The third parameter
```

In your code, you've encoded all of the `&` and `=` symbols in the URL, so you're passing a single, long parameter with no value - changing those symbols back to what they were in the javascript function should do the trick.

```
lomba_link='http://www.biblioteche.regione.lombardia.it/OPACMI01/cat/SDW'
params = urllib.urlencode([
    ('W', 'CODICE_BIBLIO+%3D+%27LO1+01%27+AND+EDITORE+PH+WORDS+%27sonzogno%27+AND+DATA_PUBBLICAZIONE+%3C+1943+ORDER+BY+ORDINAMENTO/Ascend'),
    ('M', 4),
    ('R', 'Y')
])
```

Comment: I tested code snippet but when I call read on urlopen object It doesn't grab the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to work with the brilliant `requests` library, rather than the `urllib2` library...

In regards to `urllib2.urlopen` the `params` is for POST requests. Unfortunately you need to append the query string to the url to make a GET request.

eg:

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(req + '?' + params)
```

With requests, this would be much simpler:

```
page = requests.get(some_url, params={'CalcPag': '4'})
```